# K50-HC0CSE25.0000MR Clock signal not being driven to correct logic levels

Tags: oscillator, clock, dds

I am using a [K50-HC0CSE25.0000MR](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/AVX%20PDFs/K50-HC%20Series%20Oscillators.pdf) to generate a 25MHz clock for the DDS IC [AD9833](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9833.pdf). I have hooked up the clock output directly to the MCLK input of AD9833 as shown in the diagram.[image: Schematic].

The data sheet shows the clock signal hitting 0.1VCC and 0.9VCC. However, the clock signal I sense by probing is only ranging from 1.1V to 2.8V (for 5V VCC). With active oscillators such as these, is it necessary to drop the output across a resistor? Their test setup suggests they only dropped it across a 50pF cap. I was hoping the input capacitance of the MCLK pin would be enough(3pF, data sheet says max is 50pF).

Comment: Are you sure that pin 1 (E/D) is open circuit? How are you probing the signal? Show us the waveform.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have excess load on the clock signal at 2.8V for 5V logic.

The Kyocera spec indicate Vo="1" at 0.9Vcc @ 16mA so for Vcc=5V this drop represents 0.1*5V=0.5V @16mA Zout = 0.5V/16mA = 31Ω, which is  good.

This means if you also had external clk input with 50Ω terminator which loads your Kyocera output , it should reach 50/(50+31)*5V=3.1V unless reduced by excess capacitive loading. Threshold nom is 2.5V.

You could offer more design details if you want a better answer:

- schema,  layout, waveforms, probe method, DC Voltage on each DC pin.

  - the series R on design kit schematic are DNI but 25 Ω might improve clock symmetry.  Pullup/down 100~330 Ω each also might improve integrity instead of 50Ω for ext. clock ( if used), Otherwise look for problems, this is not normal.